# Kmalloc in dentry_open(): kernel panic

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kmalloc

I'm working on kernel linux 2.6.34.14.

I added (in include/linux/fs.h) in struct file a pointer to a struct defined before, in this way:

```
struct session{
    char *session_buffer;
    loff_t session_dimension;
};

struct file {
struct session *sess_punt;

}
```

After that, I need to allocate my struct in open.c and do that in dentry_open (fs/open.c).

With this code I want to say: if there is a particular flag when open is called, then allocate the struct and the buffer in the struct.

```
if(f->f_flags & O_SESSION){
    f->sess_punt = kmalloc(sizeof(struct session), GFP_KERNEL);
    f->sess_punt -> session_buffer = kmalloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);  
    //f->sess_punt -> session_dimension = 0;
}
else f->sess_punt = NULL;
```

The problem is the following:

I compile the new kernel and everything is fine. I try to entry in that kernel but I receive the message "kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init".

Why?Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try checking for a valid pointer before using it, `f->sess_punt`

Comment: If I remove the rows with kmalloc, I can entry in that kernel and see with dmesg and some printk that else f->sess_punt = NULL; is performed without problems.

Comment: Because of course if I don't use a flag O_SESSION no one entry in that if. I don't understand why I can set the value to null but I can't set it to some other value. And why I have this error before use kmalloc, just when I try to entry in that kernel.

Comment: You get the error because the kernel tries to open /sbin and look for `init`?

Comment: Sorry but, what you mean by that?

Comment: Have you tried only removing the second kmalloc() line, or checking explicitly that f->sess_punt is a valid pointer when you do use O_SESSION?